# SaaS application architecture

Tags: saas

Can anyone shed some light on how SaaS generally host multiple instances of the application?

For example Gamepedia (a site that creates different Wikis on demand), do they spin up a docker container to run a new instance of Mediawiki (the package that Gamepedia runs on), or a separate virtual directory on the VM farm etc?

Answer (score 1):

Most SaaS providers run into this question as to how we can scale their infrastructure. There are multiple ways to scale your SaaS hosting architecture.

**Static scaling:**

1. Because SaaS works on subscriptions, scaling rules can have cap based on parameters (dimensions) like subscription size or memory consumption or CPU usage or storage size. *For eg.,* if the user base goes beyond 10K users, I'm going to deploy another instance. This capacity sizing helps us add resources in time and needed for early stage SaaS.

**Dynamic scaling:**

1. Leverage hosting cloud like [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/) or [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/autoscale/) with configuration options set to autoscale. *For eg.,* if your data storage size goes beyond X GB, you configure adding additional nodes to your elasticsearch cluster.
2. Depending on your usecases, you can consider using stateless architectures like [lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/).
3. Containerization (like docker) is another excellent way of spinning up resources. You can definitely look at plugging it in to [swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/#feature-highlights) or [mesos](http://mesos.apache.org/) to manage resources automatically. If virtualization adds overhead
4. Some apps need vertical scaling (larger storage or larger processor or larger memory) while some need horizontal scaling (adding more instances). Trends are going in favour of horizontal scaling because of cost-effectiveness. Knowing the nature of your scaling helps you build that aspect into your application and deployment architecture.
5. If using a light weight deploy management tool like [capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/) (warning: this is for RoR) is not possible, you can consider platforms like [chef](https://www.chef.io/chef/) or [puppet](https://puppet.com/)